# How can i match multiple BVPs on a finite domain so that their solution is continous?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a bvp on the form $y'' + n(x)y=h(x)$, with $y(-L) = y(L) = 0$. The n(x) is defined \begin{equation}
n(x) =
\left\{
 \begin{array}{ll}
  n_0  & \mbox{if } -L \leq x \leq -a \\
  n_1  & \mbox{if } -a \leq x \leq a \\
  n_0  & \mbox{if } a \leq x \leq L \\
 \end{array}
\right.
\end{equation}
The problem itself is fairly simple, but im not sure how to deal with the fact that n(x) has jump discontinuities. If I solve each region for its general solution i get a system of 6 equations. I can use the boundary points at f(-L) and f(L), but i dont have(as I can think of it), the points f(-a) and f(a). I want the solution to be continuous(and the derivative to be) at these points also. Do I have enough information and how can I proceed to solve the linear system for the coefficients?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you solve the ODE on the left interval, your solution $y_L$ has one degree of freedom left, which is encoded in the undetermined value of $y_L(a)$. The solution to the ODE on the middle interval has two degrees of freedom since the boundary conditions at $-a$ and $a$ are not specified, so there are two undetermined values of $y_M$, given by $y_M(-a)$ and $y_M(a)$. The solution of the ODE on the right interval, $y_R$, has one degree of freedom which is encoded in its value at $a$, namely $y_R(a)$.

So, four unknowns. Continuity at $a$ and $-a$ gives two conditions: $y_L(-a) = y_M(-a)$ and $y_M(a) = y_R(a)$. If you want the solution to be continuously differentiable at $a$ and $-a$, the derivatives have to match, which yields two more conditions: $y_L'(-a) = y_M'(-a)$ and $y_M'(a) = y_R'(a)$. In total, four conditions for four unknowns, which should (generally) yield a unique solution.